# Two ways binding textfiled in RxSwift in different type

Tags: swift, binding, reactive-programming, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I am making two ways binding for UITextField extension. It works well with string. But why not Int?
This is my extension:

```
import Foundation
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift

extension UITextField {
    func bind(with property: BehaviorRelay<String?>, bag: DisposeBag = DisposeBag()) {
        property.bind(to: self.rx.text).disposed(by: bag)
        self.rx.text.bind(to: property).disposed(by: bag)
    }

    func bind(with property: BehaviorRelay<Int?>, bag: DisposeBag = DisposeBag()) {
        property.map { intValue in
            return Int.toString(intValue) //convert from Int to String
        }.bind(to: self.rx.text).disposed(by: bag)
        self.rx.text.orEmpty.map { text in
            return String.toInt(text) ?? 0 //convert from String to Int
        }.bind(to: property).disposed(by: bag)
    }
}
```

In my viewModel:

```
let fullName = BehaviorRelay<String?>(value: nil)
let phone = BehaviorRelay<Int?>(value: nil)
```

Usage:

```
textField1.bind(with: viewModel.fullName) //working well
textField2.bind(with: viewModel.phone) //only from viewModel to textField
```

But when I use directly it working like this:

```
textField2.rx.text.map { text in
    return String.toInt(text) ?? 0
}.bind(to: viewModel.phone).disposed(by: bag)
```

Am I missing something?
Any answer are appeciated. Thanks.

Comment: Works both ways for me. Can you describe the exact steps to reproduce the problem, and what exactly happens?

Comment: I have viewModel get data from API. In my case, after loading data, it show value in the textfield, but when I change text, value in viewModel keep stable

Comment: But, when I use it directly. It working. ``` textField2.rx.text.map { text in
                    return String.toInt(text) ?? 0
                }.bind(to: viewModel.phone).disposed(by: bag)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missing pass `bag` when I call the function. Exactly, it should be:

```
let bag = DisposeBag()
textField1.bind(with: viewModel.fullName, bag: bag) //working well
textField2.bind(with: viewModel.phone, bag: bag)
```

Also I need to remove default value for avoiding forgetting in the future

```
func bind(with property: BehaviorRelay<Int?>, bag: DisposeBag) {
        property.map { intValue in
            return Int.toString(intValue) //convert from Int to String
        }.bind(to: self.rx.text).disposed(by: bag)
        self.rx.text.orEmpty.map { text in
            return String.toInt(text) ?? 0 //convert from String to Int
        }.bind(to: property).disposed(by: bag)
    }
```